# S3 bucket policy for the access from inside of ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have ECS container with php script which uses `S3` bucket.

My `S3` policy is like this below, it gives the access permission to the `ECS(or other AWS)` service.

```
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ss-bucket-stag",
            "arn:aws:s3:::ss-bucket-stag/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:PrincipalArn": "*"
            },
        }
    }
```

However when exeting php code in container,

There comes the error like this ,

```
message: fopen(https://test-stock.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/test.csv): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

I guess `fopen` from inside the container to `S3` link doesn't seen as AWS service?

If so , how can I set the bucket policy to permit access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `fopen` to directly open an HTTP URL that happens to exist in S3 does not sign the request with AWS credentials. So as far as your S3 bucket is concerned that request is coming from some random server that has no `aws:PrincipalArn` attached.

You need to use the [AWS SDK for PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) to interact with S3. When running in ECS the SDK will sign all the requests to S3 (and other AWS services) with the IAM role assigned to your ECS tasks.

Comment: Thanks to you. I understood the situation. Maybe I need to change the source code of PHP to use that library. however it is rational solution.